# Reasons why a node stream read() function might return null?

Tags: node.js, stream, fs

I am building a node application that reads a CSV file from the file system, analyzes the file, and then parses the file using the `csv-parse` module. Each of these steps are in the form of a stream, piped one into the next.

The trouble I am having is that for some files, the parse step can read the stream, but for others, the `read()` method returns `null` on the `readable` event and I don't know why.

In the code below, specifically, I will sometimes see data come through on calling `read()` on the parser stream, and other times it will return `null`. CSV files that succeed always succeed, and CSV files that fail always fail. I tried to determine some difference between the files, but other than using different field names in the first row, and slightly different data in the body, I can't see any significant difference between the source files.

**What are some reasons that a node stream's `read()` function might return `null` after a `readable` event?**

Sample code:

```
var parse = require('csv-parse');
var fs = require('fs');
var stream = require('stream');
var byteCounter = new stream.Transform({objectMode : true});
byteCounter.setEncoding('utf8');

var totalBytes = 0;

// count the bytes we have read
byteCounter._transform = function (chunk, encoding, done) {
  var data = chunk.toString();
  if (this._lastLineData) {
    data = this._lastLineData + data ;
  }
  var lines = data.split('\n');
  // this is because each chunk will probably not end precisely at the end of a line:
  this._lastLineData = lines.splice(lines.length-1,1)[0];
  lines.forEach(function(line) {
    totalBytes += line.length + 1 // we add an extra byte for the end-of-line
    this.push(line);
  }, this);
  done();
};

byteCounter._flush = function (done) {
  if (this._lastLineData) {
    this.push(this._lastLineData);
  }
  this._lastLineData = null;
  done();
};

// csv parser
var parser = parse({
  delimiter: ",",
  comment: "#",
  skip_empty_lines: true,
  auto_parse: true,
  columns: true
});

parser.on('readable', function(){
  var row;
  while( null !== (row = parser.read()) ) {
    // do stuff
  }
});

// start by reading a file, piping to byteCounter, then pipe to parser.
var myPath = "/path/to/file.csv";
var options = {
  encoding : "utf-8"
};
fs.createReadStream(myPath, options).pipe(byteCounter).pipe(parser);
```

Comment: Upon further reflection, this most likely has to do with the internals of the csv-parse module, and probably doesn't have anything to do with streams per se.

Comment: +1 for the relevant question. Have the same result here in my application and stuck for hours trying to figure out a workaround. Until now, my conclusion is: undocumented issue. Exactly the same situation: file 100% able to read and write, I try to read, it raises no errors, but the read result is **null**.